# Two PrimeNg charts in same row

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am using `chartModel` in my angular application.

I have two charts one is pie and the other is `donought` I want to decrease their size and have them on the same row how can that be done?

```
<div class="row">
  <div classs="col-md-6">
   <p-chart type="doughnut" [data]="data"></p-chart>
  </div>
  <div classs="col-md-6">
   <p-chart type="pie" [data]="data2"></p-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem with above code? `class="col-md-6"` didn't work? note that you write class with three `s`. not `classs` but `class`

Comment: yes it has no effect

Comment: I tried this code (with `class` not `classs`) in satckblitz and everything is OK. Are you sure install bootstrap?

Comment: yess silly mistake i didn't notice the typo everything works fine now.You can write an answer so i can mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to make sure that you've installed `bootstrap`. Another thing is that you write `classs` (it has one more `s`) change it to `class`.

Also if you want to have more responsive page in small size of page you need to use `col-sm-6` too.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <p-chart height="250" type="horizontalBar" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <p-chart height="250" [responsive]="false" type="horizontalBar" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

I create a working sample of two chart in one row for you: [StackBlitzLink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chart-sanbox-6wg7fx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

And the result:
[image]